# NAT gateway high availability - AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, nat, high-availability

Would you configure a NAT gateway on every AZ for HA? Is that an overkill? It costs more than $500 a year of continuous running. It does make sense for a business critical system. You could create 2 NAT gateways on 2 AZs and have the third one use one or the other to reduce some $.

My other question was, if one AZ fails, how do you automatically cut over to the NAT gateway on another AZ? As far as I can see it, you need to update the Route tables to point to the other NAT gateway manually. Do people set up a periodic ping to the NAT instance and then implement an update to the route table if it fails? 
If that's the case, assuming there will be a small outage anyway, why not create a new NAT gateway on another AZ when the old one fails and then update the route table? You will save  $500 and achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 6):

How many you need depends your RTO and RPO. Also, for reference, NAT instance and NAT Gateway ([comparison](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-nat-comparison.html)).

A NAT gateway is around $400/year depending on your region. It's highly available so you don't need redundancy in an AZ, and you can share them between your AZs. However if you want really high availability you can create one per AZ. Depending on your RPO/RTO you're probably best to start with one and create others if uptime is below what you want. They've very high bandwidth, up to 10Gbps.

Note that you pay for bandwidth between AZs. The EC2 [pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/) covers this. EC2 to EC2 traffic (ie to a NAT instance) is definitely charged. It's not clear if traffic from EC2 to a NAT Gateway is charged, but it's probably safe to assume it is.

For comparison, a t2.micro with a one year all upfront reservation is $70, you can run your own NAT instance(s). Three of them is still cheaper than the managed gateway. However bandwidth is limited, and if you have a lot of instances doing a lot of network access they will quickly become a bottleneck. You can of course scale up the t2 family as required - each jump tends to approximately double CPU and network performance.

If you really want to roll your own there's an AWS pattern [here](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/2781451301784570).

Comment: It's worth noting that the NAT Gateway and t1.micros are in a completely different ballgame when it comes to performance. If you have a small handful of hosts behind the NAT, performing very occasional outbound requests, the micro will probably work OK. However, it takes a surprisingly small number of concurrent requests to bring micro instances to their knees, which is not a problem you'll have with the NAT Gateway.

Comment: @EEAA do you mean t1 or t2? You can of course scale up the t family for better CPU and network performance

Comment: Meant t2. But either way, you're getting a *lot* higher performance for the cost of the NAT Gateway, along with HA/etc. that said, rolling your own likely makes sense in many cases.

Comment: ...which I have done in the past, but use NAT Gateways exclusively now in all of my deployments.

Comment: The comparison I linked to points that and other things out reasonably well. I'll add a little more to my answer.

Comment: *"and you can share them between your AZs"* but you'll probably pay $0.01 or $0.02/GB additional for crossing the AZ boundary.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot that's true. Will add to my answer.